# troubles with query

Tags: sql

I've got table `TContractForm` with fields `idcontract(primary key),idcntrtype(foreign key),date_begin,date_end,cost`. Also I've got 3 types of contracts:

`TRentWhouseContract` with fields `idcontract,idclient,idpdtwhs`

`TRentShoppointContract` with fields `idcontract,idclient,idshoppoint,idshoptype`

`TRentEquipContract` with fields `idcontract,idclient,ideq,amount`

`idcntrtype` - type of contract. `TContractType` - `idcntrtype(primary key),idcntrclass(foreign key),name`. `TContractClass` - `idcntrclass,name`.

I want to create a view with columns
`idcontract,idclient,contract_type(name of type),contract_class(name of class),date_begin,date_end,cost`.

But my query return nothing(I know I've got several contracts in TRentWhouseContract table(other tables has no rows)(it is without idclient because I don't know how to get the same idclient from different table if some table are empty).

```
select TCF.idcontract,
   --idclient
   TCF.date_begin,
   TCF.date_end,
   TCT.name as [type],
   TCC.name as class,
   TCF.cost
from TContractForm as TCF,
 TRentEquipContract as TREC,
 TRentShopPointContract as TRSPC,
 TRentWhouseContract as TRWC,
 TContractType as TCT,
 TContractClass as TCC
where TCF.idcontract = TREC.idcontract or TCF.idcontract = TRSPC.idcontract
  or TCF.idcontract = TRWC.idcontract and TCT.idcntrtype = TCF.idcntrtype
  and TCT.idcntrclass = TCC.idcntrclass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what I would do

```
select TCF.idcontract,
   --idclient
   TCF.date_begin,
   TCF.date_end,
   TCT.name as [type],
   TCC.name as class,
   TCF.cost
from TContractForm as TCF
JOIN TContractType as TCT
   ON TCT.idcntrtype=TCF.idcntrtype
JOIN TContractClass as TCC
   ON TCT.idcntrclass = TCC.idcntrclass
UNION
select TCF.idcontract,
   --idclient
   TCF.date_begin,
   TCF.date_end,
   TCT.name as [type],
   TCC.name as class,
   TCF.cost
from TRentWhouseContract as TCF
JOIN TContractType as TCT
   ON TCT.idcntrtype=TCF.idcntrtype
JOIN TContractClass as TCC
   ON TCT.idcntrclass = TCC.idcntrclass
UNION
select TCF.idcontract,
   --idclient
   TCF.date_begin,
   TCF.date_end,
   TCT.name as [type],
   TCC.name as class,
   TCF.cost
from TRentShoppointContract as TCF
JOIN TContractType as TCT
   ON TCT.idcntrtype=TCF.idcntrtype
JOIN TContractClass as TCC
   ON TCT.idcntrclass = TCC.idcntrclass
UNION
select TCF.idcontract,
   --idclient
   TCF.date_begin,
   TCF.date_end,
   TCT.name as [type],
   TCC.name as class,
   TCF.cost
from TRentEquipContract as TCF
JOIN TContractType as TCT
   ON TCT.idcntrtype=TCF.idcntrtype
JOIN TContractClass as TCC
   ON TCT.idcntrclass = TCC.idcntrclass
```

Answer (score 1):

How to get idclient:

```
coalesce(TREC.idclient, TRSPC.idclient,TRWC.idclient) as idclient
```

Coalesce returns first non-missing value.

As for the rest - I think you should be doing left outer joins not comma joins, since you do not have some of the records in all tables (well, no records are in all tables!).

```
select...
from TCF,TCT,TCC ... A
 left join ... TREC on A.idcontract=TREC.idcontract
 left join ... TRSPC
```

etc.

Comment: I should user `coalesce` inside `select`?